# Upload image with HttpClient

Tags: angular, http, typescript, file-upload, multipartform-data

## Problem

I try to upload an image with angular's [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) to API `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` (angular v4+). Is it supported? How to do it?

The upload works with `XMLHttpRequest` when using module like [`ng2-fancy-image-uploader`](https://github.com/ogix/ng2-fancy-image-uploader). I would prefer to use a custom method with `HttpClient` which i could put into a http service together with other methods for accessing API.

## Here is what i have tried so far:

### model.service.ts

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ModelService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public async updateAvatar(file: File): Promise<void> {

    // headers
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('avatar', file, file.name);

    const response: HttpResponse = await this.http
      .patch('https://example.com/avatar', formData, { headers, observe: 'response' })
      .toPromise();

    console.log(response.status);
  }
}
```

### avatar-uploader.component.ts

```ts
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ModelService } from './path/to/model.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-avatar-uploader',
  template: '<input type="file" #fileInput (changes)="uploadAvatar()">'
})
export class AvatarUploaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInputElement: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  public async uploadAvatar() {
    const file: File = this.fileInputElement.nativeElement.files[0];

    await this.model.updateAvatar(file);
  }

}
```

This version sends a request to (express) API, but `multer` (a library for parsing `multipart/form-data` requests) fails to parse the request.

So i guess i either use the `HttpClient` incorrectly, or it doesn't support `multipart/form-data` requests.

I guess one could send base64 encoded file or use `XmlHttpRequest`, but i ask specifically about `HttpClient`'s ability to do it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For me the trick was not to set the content-type to multipart/form-data. But that was done automatically for me.

```
<label>
  <input type="file" (change)="setFiles($event)" style="display:none" multiple/>
  <a mat-raised-button color="primary">
    <mat-icon>file_upload</mat-icon>
    Select Documents
  </a>
</label>
```

Here's my code that uploads multipart/form-data. No need to set the headers.

```
private setFile(event) {
    let files = event.srcElement.files
    if (!files) {
      return
    }

    let path = `${environment.celoApiEndpoint}/api/patientFiles`
    let data = {"patientData": {
      "uid": "",
      "firstName": "",
      "lastName": "",
      "gender": "Not Specified",
      "dateOfBirth": ""
    }}
    // let headers = new HttpHeaders()
    //   .set('content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW')
    // let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'multipart/form-data')
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      formData.append(i.toString(), files[i], files[i].name);
    }
    formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(data));
    this.http.post(path, formData).subscribe(
      (r)=>{console.log('got r', r)}
    )
  }
```

Comment: Is FormData() cross-browser supported? What about Safari browser?

Comment: @MichałZiobro https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried to set encryption and all that stuff in the options and would never have tried not to set options :)

Comment: Adding 'Content-Type' or 'Accept' to the header will bring pain and suffering: the upload will not work... the question that still remains is WHY?!

Comment: Thank you for the multipart/form-data tip. I was setting the multipart headers and my reqquets weren't showing up on the server, even though they worked perfect in Insomnia (with the multipart headers set though). I've been at this for over 12 hours!!

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the issue is with angular, I used the same code to send a file to the server (I am using spring in backend), the only difference is I am not observing the request or converting the response to promise.

See my code below:

```
let formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload);

this.http.put(this.usersUrl, formData).subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log(data); 
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```