# Image upload from Angular 5 to Node.Js server

Tags: node.js, image-uploading, angular5, multer

I'm creating a website and using a node.js server to store images. I have the server and website setup however when I my post request doesn't seem to send the image. The server detects the post request but doesn't receive the image. I've am new to node.js and cloud computing. 
Thank you!

The post request in Angular:

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
    selectedFile: File = null;
    onFileSelected(event) {
        this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
        console.log(event);
        console.log(this.selectedFile);
    }
    onUpload() {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.httpClient.post('ip:port/header',
      {
        'message': 'Handling POST requests to /images',
        'createdImage': {
          'name': 'name',
          'size': 'size',
          'imageFile': this.selectedFile
        }
      })
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response);
          console.log(fd);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error, fd);
        });
    console.log(this.selectedFile);
  }
}
```

Node.js post request handler:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png'){
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
};

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits:{
        fileFilter: fileFilter
}});


router.post('/', upload.single('imageFile'),(req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    const image = {
        //attributes of item that server will request (more important for db
        name: req.body.name,
        size: req.body.size,
        imageFile: req.body.imageFile

    };

    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Handling POST requests to /images,',
        createdImage: image
    });
});
```

Comment: Is `this.selectedFile` an HTML file input element? Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects for examples.

Comment: HI, sorry, I should've had in that part, I added the selectedFile code in at the top of the Angular code

Comment: I don't know what is "httpClient" there, but it looks like you are building `FormData` object and then do not pass it to the `this.httpClient.post` method. Maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/a/47277805/6352710 - looks like it is a very similar situation, i.e., use `FormData` object to append any data you want, and then pass just that object to the `this.httpClient.post` method.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass your created FormData object as body of POST request, because you need to send your image as multipart type.

Also you need to change `fd.append('imageFile', ...);` to get file in backend, cause this name must match with first param of `upload.single` method.